# concatenate two lists of string in r

Tags: r, string, data-manipulation

Here is my sample:

```
a = c("a","b","c")
b = c("1","2","3")
```

I need to concatenate a and b automatically. The result should be "a 1","a 2","a 3","b 1","b 2","b 3","c 1","c 2","c 3".

For now, I am using the paste function:

```
paste(a[1],b[1])
```

I need an automatic way to do this. Besides writing a loop, is there any easier way to achieve this?

Comment: What's wrong with paste?

Comment: They all should have space. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other options are :

```
paste(rep.int(a,length(b)),b)
```

or :

```
with(expand.grid(b,a),paste(Var2,Var1))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
c(outer(a, b, paste))

# [1] "a 1" "b 1" "c 1" "a 2" "b 2" "c 2" "a 3" "b 3" "c 3"
```

Comment: outer FTW ! I always forget that function :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
c(sapply(a, function(x) {paste(x,b)}))
[1] "a 1" "a 2" "a 3" "b 1" "b 2" "b 3" "c 1" "c 2" "c 3"
```

*edited* `paste0` into `paste` to match OP update